# History on the plane wreck in Solheimasandur as a tourist attraction?

Tags: aircraft, iceland, history

This question is not about travelling advice, but rather about some history.

On the Solheimasandur beach in Iceland, there's an abandoned plane wreck that has been lying there since 1973. When visiting it last summer, I could tell by the names & dates carved into it that very few people visited this plane before 2010-ish.

I am wondering though: is this correct? Does anybody know when tourists started to be aware of this plane wreck's existence?

For the record: the plane was featured in Sigur Rós' movie called "Heima", released in 2007. Many people talking about the plane these days say that they first saw it in that movie. Again though, I'm not sure if that movie is what spurred tourists to go there.

Answer (score 2):

Massively was around the date of the movie I would be guessing, but it does help the fact that the tourism departments of the area DO have a whole paragraph talking about it as an attraction... One full paragraph out of 4 for the entire beach so yeah, I would say they pushed for mass tourism on that plane...